# Misunderstanding of event.listener to check user device

Tags: symfony, user-agent

I have set up a simple listener and service to check if the user is using a mobile device. I will gladly share to you my research to help others who don't understand quite easily this method.

My goal is to know if my user is using a mobile device or not at first

however I'm stuck in how to manipulate this function, I really had a hard time understanding how that works.

Here is my code

**in my `service.yml`**

```
template.loader:
      class: ST\BackofficeBundle\EventListener\DeviceListener
      tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

**My even listener I created to check if the user is using a mobile**

```
class DeviceListener
{
    public function onKernelView(getResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
       $event->getRequest()->getSession()->set('mobile', true);

       $response = new Response();
       $response->setContent($event);

       $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Is there any line missing that I should do here or in a controller?

i saw there is this line in the [symfony doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#accessing-request-data) `$_SERVER ($request->headers->get('User-Agent'))` should I use it somewhere in my code?

thank you

Comment: What's your goal? Do you want to modify response according to `User-Agent`?

Comment: Hi @DrKey My goal is to detect if the user is using a mobile device and then send a template specifically for mobile. But at first i need to know how to know if the user is using a mobile device. That is why I tried to make a simple event listener with a service and.....i'm stuck here to know how to get to know if the user has a mobile. i thought maybe I need to write things in the controller? of things is missing in my listener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to modify your response according to `User-Agent` then I would create a `kernel.response` listener.

Therefore in your `services.yml` declare something like

```
template.loader:
      class: ST\BackofficeBundle\EventListener\DeviceListener
      tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

This way your listener will be called just before sending response. Of course you can modify your response as you need:

```
public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
   $response = $event->getResponse();
   $request = $event->getRequest();

   if ($request->headers->get('User-Agent') == 'whatever') {
       $response->setContent('hello');
   }

   $event->setResponse($response);
}
```

For more detailed informations about kernel events, take a look at [this page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html).